# How to subtract or add two coordinates

Tags: java, methods, coordinates, void

I am trying to subtract and add two coordinates of two cities. I would like to do this in a void method. What are your suggestions, how should I do this?

**For example:**

I would like to subtract coordinates of `city1 (x1, y1)` with `city2(x2, y2)` and then call it in main class. So how to do it?

I have written this code below, but it is not working or I don't know how to call it...

Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Coordinates paris = new Coordinates(48.830103, 2.562957);
        Coordinates rioDeJaneiro = new Coordinates(-22.492147, -43.143827);
```

Coordinates class:

```
 public class Coordinates {

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public Coordinates(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

     public void subtract(Coordinates otherCoordinates) {
           new Coordinates(this.latitude - otherCoordinates.getLatitude(),
                            this.longitude - otherCoordinates.getLongitude());
     }
```

Comment: "*...it is not working or I dont know how to call it...*" - What is that suppose to mean? Do you get a compile error? Runtime Exception? Unexpected behaviour? Please be precise and include as much relevant information as possible.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks, yes I didnt explain it properly. I dont get the results I want. The results are wrong. I dont get any errors, but it doesnt work properly. I will be more mindful how I ask next time.

Comment: Please create a [MRE], sample input, expected and observed output.

Comment: @Escape what is your expected output? Do you want new coordinates in paris object or new object.

Comment: @RamPrakash yes I want new coordinates, like if I would do 3 - 1 = 2, but just with coordinates. And that it is a method of void type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code won't work as you expect. 
Your subtract method supposed to be something like below

```
public void subtract(Coordinates otherCoordinates) {
                this.latitude = this.latitude- otherCoordinates.getLatitude();
                this.longitude = this.longitude- otherCoordinates.getLongitude();
 }
```

if latitude and longitude are immutable then

```
public Coordinates subtract(Coordinates otherCoordinates) {
           return  new Coordinates(this.latitude - otherCoordinates.getLatitude(), 
                                    this.longitude - otherCoordinates.getLongitude());
  }
```

Comment: Not necessarily no. If `Coordinates` is designed as immutable, creating a new `Coordinates`-object is the proper way. Please ask for clarification before posting speculative answers.

Comment: @Turing85 good point..

Comment: @RamPrakash Thanks. How do I call this method in my main class? Like this: 
paris.subtract(london);

Comment: @Escape add Coordinates class and main class to your question

Comment: @RamPrakash I added main and Coordinates class

Answer (score 0):

That works.  Another way is:

```
public static void subtract(Coordinates city1, Coordinates city2, Coordinates result) {
            result.longitude =  city1.getLongitude() - city2.getlongitude());
            result.latitude = city1.getLatitude() - city2.getLatitude();
}
```

However, your posted solution with a modification is best (as has been pointed out).

```
public Coordinates subtract(Coordinates otherCoordinates) {
            return new Coordinates(this.latitude - otherCoordinates.getLatitude(), 
                    this.longitude - otherCoordinates.getLongitude());
}
```

In the later case and presuming that `subtract` is a method in the `Coordinates` class you would call it as follows:

```
Coordinates city1 = new Coordinates(...);
Coordinates city2 = new Coordinates(...);

Coordinates result = city1.subtract(city2);
```

Comment: It works yes, but employs side-effects. I would not recommend this solution. I would rather recoomend working with return values.

Comment: I completely agree.  But the OP wanted to use a void method.  Just trying to comply

Comment: There is nothing in the post that out-right says "the method must have a `void` return type" =). As far as I see it, there are conflicting information. The method is implemented as if OP wants to return a new `Coordinates`, while the method is defined as `void`.